# Using textbox as value

Tags: javascript, html

The last thing I cant get to work is to make this part `.namefield.value = 'name';` to be based on a textarea.

I've tried altering the value part `.value = 'name'` to be directed to the form/id's to the textarea itself but that didn't work.

The textarea with submit button I've tried to use comes from dreamweaver;

```
<form id='input' method='post' action='' >
   Name: <input type='text' name='Name' />
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

The html/JavaScript which I am learning with is:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="main" width="1000" height="1000" src="main.php"></iframe>
<button id="btnMain">Go</button>
  <script>    
     function load() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btnMain');
        btn.onclick = function(){
        var ifrm = document.getElementById('main');
        ifrm.contentWindow.document.forms['searchForm'].namefield.value = 'name';
     };    
   }
   window.onload = load;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Tim_Holt/0a9krnao/](http://jsfiddle.net/Tim_Holt/0a9krnao/4/)

Comment: what is `searchForm`

Comment: Thats the formid of a form in main.php.
On this moment if i click the button, it places 'name' in the field on that form

Comment: if `ifrm.contentWindow.document.forms['searchForm'].namefield.value = 'name';` puts `name` in the field you want to read, then just use `x=ifrm.contentWindow.document.forms['searchForm'].namefield.value;` to access that value?

Comment: I think thats the other way around, the thing i like to have is not to display the word 'name' in the field of the form on main.php, but the value of a textbox to be placed in the form on main.php.

Comment: the value of the textbox in the iframe?

Comment: Yeah so this part : " < button id="btnMain">Go< /button> " , would be replaced with a textbox, and that textbox would be the value instead of 'name'. Because if i click on the button i only get 'name' in the form on main.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle for my solution to your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/1nqdsyhu/
Here's the snippet of HTML/jQuery code

HTML

```
<button id='btnMain'>Enter</button>
<input type='text' name='value instead of 'name'' value='Write your name here' />
<ul>
</ul>

</br>
</br>
The frame wich has the form hasnt been includedbecause i dont know how to, but the form        above should be the value instead of the word 'name' shown as value in de javascript, wich at this point will be placed in the iframe form.
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnMain').on('click', function() {
        $('ul').append('<li>' + $('input').val() + '</val>');
    });

});
```